# iOS - Google cast sdk failure

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, chromecast, google-cast

I just got some issues with google-cast-sdk (v3.5 cocoapod).[Click here to see illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Es7Q.png).
It seens to only happen on iOS 10. 
Anyone has the same problem. Could u guys can tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Maybe you are not creating the context early enough. You should do it in the applicationDidLoad: method of your app delegate.

Comment: Oh thankyou. I'll try. As i see, the crashes happened since I installed the new version of google-cast-sdk (v3.3 -> v3.5). Do u think that is the reason ?

Comment: The new version might enforce the creation of the context a bit more

Comment: @LiorPollak Thankyou

Comment: @DarkInnocence Thanks for your comment